# Rails Kaminari pagination, set record index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kamianri

I'm paginating using Kaminari pagination gem. I want to set the starting page, so the default page will be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4*, 5, 6,...].

My current pagination code:

```
@event = Event.order(start_date: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(1)
@items = Item.where(event_id: @event.first._id)
```

I want the first page displayed to be the most current event, so older events will be previous pages, and future events will be next pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this would be to:

a) Count the events that are before the current date, eg. `previous_events = Event.count(:start_date.lte => DateTime.now.utc)`

b) Work out how many pages of events that covers, eg. `previous_pages = previous_events/Event.default_per_page`

c) Floor it to get the page you need to start on, eg. `start_page = previous_pages.floor`

Then pass this into your controller code:

```
@events = Event.order(start_date: :asc).page(start_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly broad so I am not sure exactly what you are looking for. If you just want to set the default page you could call something like

```
current_page = params[:page] ||= 4  #or whatever you want the default page to be

@event = Event.order(start_date: :asc).page(current_page).per(1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Similar to the answers below, you could use events occurring in the future to determine your page:

```
current_page = params[:page] ||= Event.where(:start_date > DateTime.now.utc).count #This will tell you how many events are in the future

@event = Event.order(start_date: :asc).page(current_page).per(1)
```

Comment: This is close! I want to pick the current page like `Event.where(:start_date.gte => DateTime.now.utc)`

Comment: so if you have 100 future events, you would be set to page 100?

Comment: The way this is set up, yes. 1 Event per page. Todays event on the current page. And future events on 'previous' pages. Events in the past on 'next' pages

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query that pagination uses adds `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` to the end of the SQL statement. This means your result set will only have 1 record and you won't know at what index the current event is in. You'd have to do some more work to find the index out of all your events then pass that index as the `OFFSET`, i.e. the `.page()` method. Basically, get `all` of your events, find the event that is current, then get the index of it, and pass that index into your `page` method. Here's some pseudocode:

```
all_events = Event.order(start_date: :asc).all
current_event = all_events.detect { |e| e.start_date.to_date == Time.now.to_date }
index = all_events.index(current_event)
@events = Event.order(start_date: :asc).page(params[:page] || index).per(1)
```

That might be close enough to work. Note: this approach only works because your `LIMIT` is 1 i.e. your argument to `page`.